# Error using Lodash template render UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lodash

I use `Lodash template`, but I don't sure I code correct. Please help me review and talk for me the error.
This is image error : 
[image]

---

Code use `Lodash template` :

```
template: function(data) {
    this.element = _.template([
    '<% _.forEach(data, function(data) { %>',
      '<a class="item-recipe <%= data.highlighted %> " href="javascript:void(0);">',
        '<span class="attribution">',
          '<span class="title-recipe"><%= data.title %></span>',
          '<span class="metadata-recipe">',
            '<span class="author-recipe"><%= data.source.name %></span>',
            '<span class="bookmarks-recipe">',
              '<span class="icon-bookmark">',
                '</span> 0</span>',
              '</span>',
            '</span>',
        '<img id="<%= data.id %>" src="<%= data.source.image %>">',
      '</a>',
    '<% }); %>'
    ].join('\n'));


    return _.template(this.element)({
      data: data
    })
```

---

And append it to UI:

```
var recipe_data = self.template(data.responseJSON);
    $('#js-recipe-data').append(recipe_data);
```

Comment: Is it backbone view? Why do you set `this.element = _.template([`?